# I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException while executing my test case

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, page-objects, exception

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException while executing my test case , I am using Page Object Modle with PageFactory ,following are the code snippets

**TestBase Class:**

```
ackage com.base;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import pagefactory.Scorex_LoginPage;
import pagefactory.Scorex_HomePage;

public class TestBase {

       protected WebDriver driver;
       protected String baseUrl = "http://scorex.domain.com/";
       protected Scorex_LoginPage objLogin;
       protected Scorex_HomePage objHome;

       @BeforeMethod
       public void initializeBrowser() {
             driver = new FirefoxDriver();
             driver.get(baseUrl);
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             driver.manage().window().maximize();

       }
       @AfterMethod
       public void closeBrowser(){
             driver.quit();

       }
    }
```

**Test Case Class:**

```
package tests;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.base.TestBase;

public class Scorex_LoginTestCases extends TestBase{

    @Test(priority=1) //TC01
    public void Scorex_valid_email_password()
    {
        objLogin.loginScoreAs("superadmin@domain.com", "superadmin");
        String DashboardUserName = objHome.getHomePageUserName();
        Assert.assertTrue(DashboardUserName.contains("Super Admin"));
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for the lack of stack trace in question. Stacktrace contains a line number where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

On the *Scorex_LoginTestCases* (Btw, we do not use underscore in names in Java ([See conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)), the objects *objLogin* and *objHome* are not initialized.

On the *TestBase*, you should initialize them using the PageFactory's method *initElements*. You can see a sample [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory#a-simple-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Page Factory we need to initialize the Page Object:
You can initialize with the help of below sample code:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl);
Scorex_LoginTestCases loginTest = PageFactory.initElements(driver,Scorex_LoginTestCases.class);
loginTest.Scorex_valid_email_password();
```

And please follow the conventions as method name always starts with a small character and please avoid using underscore. For more information on conventions please click [here.](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

For more information on Page Factory please click [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-pattern-model-page-factory/).